# Is there a way to use the magrittr pipe operator %>% to get multiple outputs?

Tags: r, magrittr

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve multiple outputs from a singular input using the `magrittr` package in R in such a way that you could achieve the output of this:

```
rnorm(30) %>%
mean

rnorm(30) %>%
median
```

without needing to call `rnorm(30)` twice.

Comment: This works: `rnorm(30) %>% list(mean(.), median(.))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put them in a vector together:

```
rnorm(30) %>% { c(mean = mean(.), median = median(.)) }
#       mean     median 
# -0.2477345 -0.1126395
```

The curly brackets are the key here.  Without them you'll get the `rnorm(30)` vector with the mean and median values concatenated to the end.

Another option is to write your own function.

```
f <- function(x) c(mean = mean(x), median = median(x))
rnorm(30) %>% f
#        mean      median 
# -0.12908354 -0.06667819
```

Comment: Thank you this works well, I will be using list rather than c as I need to combine multiple data types, but the concept helped a lot (and the mention of the {} brackets.